# Output mysql result as an array of the form (column name => possible values for column name)

Tags: php, mysql, associative-array

I have database such as

[image]

I want to create an associative array such that each `att_name` value is associated with its possible values from `att_value`:

```
array('att_name' => array('att_value_1', 'att_value_2', 'att_value_3'))
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: `mysql_fetch_assoc` of course...

Comment: Get the rows in whatever way you want and then iterate over them and create the a new array in the format you want. There is not SQL query that can generate that format for you. This is pretty straightforward, I suggest to make yourself more familiar with arrays: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php and maybe the `mysql_fetch_*` functions: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mysql.php.

Comment: Why do you want to create a array like that? `mysql_fetch_assoc` gives you a (key, value) array.

Comment: thanks for the help guys !! , it helped !!! , sorry for not voting up !; i don't have necessary points to vote up !!

Answer (score 1):

While it is easily possible to do this simply by selecting the results you want and iterating them in PHP to create the data structure you want, you could sub some of the work out to MySQL with [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
$query = "
  SELECT att_name, GROUP_CONCAT(att_value SEPARATOR ',') AS values
  FROM table_name
  GROUP BY att_name
";
$result = mysql_query($query);

$array = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $array[$row['att_name']] = explode(',', $values);
}

print_r($array);
```

Of course, this only works if your values will never contain the character (or sequence of characters) you use for the `SEPARATOR` in the MySQL query, so the safer pure-PHP way would be:

```
$query = "
  SELECT att_name, att_value
  FROM table_name
";
$result = mysql_query($query);

$array = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $array[$row['att_name']][] = $row['att_value'];
}

print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
$sql = "SELECT * from tablename";
$result = mysql_query($sql,$con);
$final_array=array();
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result))
   {
      $final_array[$row->att_name][0]=$row->att_value_1;
      $final_array[$row->att_name][1]=$row->att_value_2;
      ....
      ....
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

This way :

```
SELECT
    item,
    att_name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(att_value SEPARATOR "<!>") AS att_value
FROM
    table
GROUP BY
    att_name
```

Will give you something like that :

```
item    att_name    att_value
-----------------------------
books   height      150 mm<!>250 mm
books   price       rs:20<!>Rs:20
books   size        15 pg<!>30 pg<!>60 pg
books   width       300 mm<!>400 mm
```

You have to explode the result from `att_value` by a `<!>`. I use this `<!>` so it highly impossible to have a value inside `att_value` with this. If you think you would someday use this, take another separator. Example : `[{--}]`, `_SEPARATOR_`, `[_-CUT-_]`, etc. Something you are sure at 100% you won't use a choice but always as a separator to split the text.

So example :

```
$SQL = 'SELECT item, att_name, GROUP_CONCAT(att_value SEPARATOR "<!>") AS att_value FROM table GROUP BY att_name';
$Query = mysql_query($SQL) or die('MySQL Error : '.mysql_error());

while($Assoc = mysql_fetch_assoc($Query)){
    $Assoc['att_value'] = ($Assoc['att_value'] != '' ? explode('<!>', $Assoc['att_value']) : NULL);
    print_r($Assoc);
}
```